# Cant remap results from mongoose find operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an API route that must give me back all the invoices and so I have `Invoice` model. There is a `supplierId` field in that model, that saves the `_id` of the respective supplier of the invoice, which means that whenever I want to pull the invoices, I must also pull the respective suppliers and incldue them in the response, and that is my issue, for some reason, I can't work on the results as I do on normal arrays:

```
const getAllInvoices = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const invoices = await Invoice.find().exec();    
    const suppliers = await suppliersService.getAllSuppliers();

    const invoicesWithSuppliers = invoices.map((invoice) => {
      return {
        number: invoice.number,
        supplierName: suppliers.find((supplier) => supplier._id === invoice.supplierId).name,
      };
    });

    console.log(invoicesWithSuppliers); // outputs nothing

    res.json(invoices); // and this now for some reason also stops working and returns {}
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
};
```

And `suppliersService.getAllSuppliers()`:

```
 const getAllSuppliers = async () => {
  try {
    const suppliers = await Supplier.find().exec();

    return suppliers;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the result of find is array of Model, not a common array of object...

you can convert the result of find and working with them:

**note**: when you use awai, no need to `exec()`

```
let invoices = await Invoice.find(); 
invoices = invoices.map((inv) => inv.toObject({ getters: true }));
let suppliers = await suppliersService.getAllSuppliers();
suppliers = suppliers.map((sup) => sup.toObject({ getters: true }));
//do somthing
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I just managed to get my debugger working and figured that too and I ended up digging in the _doc field, and also converting _id.toString(), but your approach will probably be easier, as I will be able to work with them as with normal objects. I was just confused, because, when I try to work withg them, they dont behave like normal objects, but when I send them to my client with json, I receive them as normal objects.

Comment: you right, but this is a feature of mangoose :) Nothing can be done

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly no need to run a second query to get the suppliers data when you can just use [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method which lets you reference documents in other collections by automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

Also, chain the [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method to return only plain objects from the query, not mongoose documents like the `find()` method.
It also has the benefit of less average execution time simply because the documents returned with the [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method are plain javascript:

```
const getAllInvoices = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const invoices = await Invoice.find()
        .populate('supplierId', 'name')
        .lean();    
    res.json(invoices);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
};
```